# Naive Gaussian Elimination - Sparse and Full matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods

I am currently playing with numerical methods in MATLAB. I am trying to understand the dependence of time taken to solve sparse/full matrices of the same dimensions, with respects to different sizes of n.

My understanding is that in general, sparse matrices take shorter time to be solved as compared to full matrices. However, when i used the Naive Gaussian Elimination method, the sparse matrices took significantly longer to be solved. I have been researching online for reasons but to no avail.

Thus, I am here with this question in hopes that someone will be able to enlighten me. Thanks in advance!!!

These are my plots produced for better understanding of my question : 
[Sparse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEnmE.jpg)

[Full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LORKf.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and also check How to Ask Good Questions so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Modern computers have pretty large amounts of Random Access Memory available, and also the CPUs are pretty fast. In that case, systems of linear equations with matrices up to several thousands of columns/rows are processed very fast when treated directly as *dense* , regardless of their actual sparsity. The difference between "dense" and "sparse" algorithms becomes obvious in favour of "sparse" ones when the matrix sizes grow large, above 10000 or so (it all depends on the quality of a particular "sparse" algorithm, as well as on the CPU and RAM properties of the user's computer). "Sparse" algorithms have special schemes to store the matrix, to provide access to its elements, to modify them, etc. Those overheads can slow down the solution algorithm for not-so-large matrices in comparison with straightforward implementations for dense matrices.